# Set child input values after parent AJAX using refs

Tags: reactjs

**Parent component**

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {

  someModel: any = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(...).then(response => {
      this.someModel = response;
      this.setState({});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent someModel={this.someModel} />
    );
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

**Child component**

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {

  nameControl: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.senderControl.current.disabled = true;
    this.nameControl.current.value = this.props.someModel.name;  // is NOT called on props update
  }

  render() {

    this.nameControl.current.value = this.props.someModel.name;  // this.nameControl is NULL on first render

    return (
      <input ref={this.nameControl} name="name" className="form-control pl-3 pr-3" placeholder="Name" />
    );
  };
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

**Expectation**

1. Parent component sends an AJAX request
2. Parent passes model received from the AJAX response to the Child using props
3. Child component re-renders HTML with new value and updates input `ref` that came from props

**Actual**

1. ...
2. ...
3. Child component can't update input refs with values from props if
   props were set after parent AJAX request

- Child input ref can't be updated from `componentDidMount`, because it's not triggered by props update
- Child input ref can't be updated from `render`, because input ref is NULL on the first render

**Question**

Is there any single built-in React method that I could use to update child refs when parent AJAX requested is completed, without hacking and copy-pasting the same code into multiple methods, e.g. `componentDidMount` for the first render and `render` for all following props updates?

P.S. I also don't want to pass refs from parent to child, because parent couldn't know anything about child structure.

Comment: `this.nameControl.current.value = this.props.someModel.name;` is definitely wrong inside of `render` - use the `render` function for rendering stuff and not for business logic. And have you looked at `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: @goto1 First, in my case this method looks hacky as well, because I don't want to compare previousState, currentState, etc, I just want to update values in child component when parent finished its job, no conditions. Second, yes, I looked even at that hacky method and it says that `This method is not called for the initial render`

Comment: There's nothing "hacky" about that method - this is exactly what you need. You don't need to compare `prevState` with `currState`, just compare the `prevProps` with `currProps` to see if `props` have changed and do whatever business logic you need there (update values in child component). And, you don't need this to be called for the initial render, you're only interested when new `props` are passed after `AJAX` request completes.

Comment: _I just want to update values in child component when parent finished its job, no conditions_ - you don't need `ref` for that. Take a look at [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-feather-4cmbm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @Yousaf Yes, I want to update child based on props from parent. I don't want to set input `value` attribute directly in HTML, because in this case I'd have to add `onChange` handler, as well, which is more complicated that using refs.

Comment: _because in this case I'd have to add `onChange` handler_ - you only need to add `onChange` handler if you want to get the value of input after user inputs something in the input field.

Comment: @Yousaf Exactly, input should work both ways. Populate input value from props. Then, user should be able to change value in the input field + I need to get input value on submit.

Comment: Wait, in that case, you should just pass a simple prop from parent (e.g. a string) to the child, then handle those updates using the `onChange` handler inside the child component. Not sure why over complicating this with the use of `refs` - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs and https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs.

Comment: In that case, you should use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. If you don't want to use `componentDidUpdate` method, then [here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-frog-c9nxv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) how you can do this using ref. Keep in mind that input components should be `controlled` components in React, so it is better to use `componentDidUpdate` method and use `state` to update the value of the input.

Comment: @Yousaf you should definitely keep **all** business logic out of the `render` method - "The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state" https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render

Comment: @goto1 where am i modifying the state?

Comment: @Yousaf you have an `if` statement inside `render` that updates `this.nameControl`, which violates the "render() function should be pure" principle.

Comment: @goto1 updating value contained in `ref` is not same as updating `state`

Comment: @Yousaf updating `ref` is making the `render()` function impure, which again, is not what's recommended in the docs.